# Matlab timestamp conversion

Tags: matlab, date, datetime, label

I would like to alter the format of some  time-stamps
I have obtain them in this form

```
2.010010101000000e+07
```

I would like to convert them into the form

```
7.341390416666666e+05
```

The target is using them as time-stamps in the x-label of plots.
I tried the `datenum` but i think i am not on the correct path to solving this

Comment: How is `2.01....e+07` conected to `7.34...e+05`? I do not understand what kind of conversion you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you really mean x-label or do you mean x-tick-label? If the latter case is true, you might want to check out the datetick() command. Probably datetick(x, 'yyyymmmdd HHMM').

Comment: @Nras thank for the additional info, i will check that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you do not make it clear, I guess you have a number representing yyyymmdd or similar, and you want to convert it to a datenum.  You can do this using a format command with `datenum`.

```
d = 20100101;
d2 = datenum(num2str(d),'yyyymmdd');
```

Depending how you are obtaining `20100101` in the first place you might be able to make your life easier by reading it from file in a different way in the first place, though.

Comment: yes my mistake to oversight that clarification i am trying to alter them into the yyyymmdd HHMM form

Comment: If you look at the `datenum` and `datestr` help it will show you how to use different formatting (including custom formats) to change between a `datenum` and various string formats.

Comment: i have been looking at them and datevec as well, i will look them a bit more.thank you